# Showing $k^2 + m^2$ is odd when $k$ is odd and $m$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Prove that if $k$ is any odd integer and $m$ is any even integer, then, $k^2 + m^2$ is odd.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts 
on it are; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level

And here is a tutorial for writing math symbols and expressions:
[MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Note: If $k$ is odd, then $k = 2n+1$ for some integer $n$. If $m$ is even then $m = 2l$ for some integer $l$. These are the definitions of even and odd.

Then $$ k^2 + m^2 = (2n+1)^2+(2l)^2= 4n^2 +2n+1 +4l^2$$
$$4n^2 +2n+1 +4l^2 = 2(2n^2+n+2l^2)+1$$

Let $j=(2n^2+n+2l^2)$, then $2(2n^2+n+2l^2)+1= 2j+1$ for some integer j, which is the definition of odd.

Answer (score 2):

If $k$ is odd then $k=2a+1$ for some $a\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $m$ is even then $m=2b$ for some $b\in\mathbb{Z}$. So the equation is now \begin{align*}
k^2+m^2&=(2a+1)^2+(2b)^2\\
&=4a^2+4a+1+4b^2\\
&=[4(a^2+a+b^2)]+1
\end{align*}
Notice that the expression in brackets $[\ ]$ is even because it is divisible by $4$ which implies it is divisible by $2$. An even plus $1$ is odd.

Comment: Can we prove that even plus 1 is odd?

Comment: @Nitin If $2$ divided two consecutive numbers, then it also has to divide the difference $1$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Well, this answer claims even is defined as of form 2n and odd is of form 2n+1.  So an even plus 1 is... 2n+1.  Of course we have to show a number being even or odd are mutually exclusive and exhaustive...

Comment: ....this was a joke. I know OP in real life

Comment: @Nikhil OP, any thoughts so far?

Answer (score 1):

I always find it helpful to think about why something is true before I try to prove it. If I square an even number, I get another even number. If I square an odd number I get an odd number. Obviously when I add these together I get another odd number.

Now try to show why squaring preserves the evenness or oddness of a number.